# Raspberry Pi Operating System Update?

Tags: debian, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I have two Pis, a b+ and a 2. I have an operating system (Debian) that i use on the b+ that i'd like to use on the 2. Is there any way that i can make the operating system work for the Pi 2 without downloading a fresh one?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to put SD card from b+ R-Pi to New R-Pi 2 ?
I'm not sure but when I put my SD card from R-Pi 2 to R-Pi B+ it works.
How old is Raspbian on your old R-Pi ?

Maybe this helps You : (Article about preparing SD Card with OS for R-Pi 2) :

http://thepihut.com/blogs/raspberry-pi-tutorials/16982376-updating-raspbian-on-your-microsd-for-the-raspberry-pi-2